# matplotlib stacked bar chart with dynamic threshold line

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I'd like to have a stacked bar chart, where there is a threshold line. Above threshold line, bar color should be red, and below threshold line bar color should be green. The problem is, threshold value is not constant, it may have different value for each x value. And I'd like to update this threshold value for some x value whenever I want.
How to achieve this? Obviously the y argument of bar charts should be dynamic, maybe I should pass a function for them? Please help me with this.
Also I'm thinking the threshold should be a function as well, as I will update it as well

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some example data
threshold = 43.0
values = np.array([30., 87.3, 99.9, 3.33, 50.0])
x = range(len(values))

# split it up
above_threshold = np.maximum(values - threshold, 0)
below_threshold = np.minimum(values, threshold)

# and plot it
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, below_threshold, 0.35, color="g")
ax.bar(x, above_threshold, 0.35, color="r",
        bottom=below_threshold)

# horizontal line indicating the threshold
ax.plot([0., 4.5], [threshold, threshold], "k--")

ax.show()
```

Comment: Why don't you create two data lists: one with the values below and the other with the values above the threshold and plot the like stacked bars instead?

Comment: But, when threshold value changes, how will I update the bar charts' corresponding  `y ` value? And the  `bottom ` argument of 1 of the bar chart should also be updated, but how to do all of these??

Comment: You can change threshold values the way you prefer, you'll just have to update the values in two lists.

Comment: I think  `below_threshold ` and   `above_threshold ` arguments should be functions. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use stacked bars instead of bar plot with threshold. You can see it in this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html) (just eliminate the error bars).

Comment: But I want to show the threshold line with a dashed line.